# how can i control jpa data source creation

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I have eclipse link data sources created using weblogic server. I have 2 data sources one for read and another for write. I want to have default load the the read data source and in run time(i mean request) want to create the write data source.

is there any option like that. i have tried with 2 data sources not above said.

can any one tell me how to proceed.

Comment: What is the purpose of using multiple data sources?

Comment: I have multiple servers one for read and another for write. also have multiple environments where in each environment this read and write are not same. one will have both read and write as same. another will have read and write. my question would is there any way i can control the error if no data sources is defined in my server and it is present in persistence.xml